# How to dribble properly in FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

I am new to FIFA and do not know how to dribble properly during games. I can execute most of the "tricks" in the arena (1-on-1 vs goalkeeper) on a regular basis, so once I know what to do I can pull it of.

But during games it is very complicated to dribble once I select Semi-Pro, as I do not know what to do.

So here are my questions:

- Can I dribble on reaction (depending on what the defender does) or do I have to guess the right dribbling?
- What tricks are considered best when trying to bypass a defender (he is in front of you)?
- What tricks are considered best once I have nearly outrun a defender (both run next to each other)?
- Are there any good tutorials on this except the basic "How to execute"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you are new to FIFA, the best advice regarding skill moves is:

**Dont do it (yet).**

The effective use of skill moves is pretty hard to master and randomly executing them will lead to loss of the ball in 90% of the cases.

Having said that, here are some tips:

- Start getting used to dribbling without the special moves. In FIFA 12, manual dribbling (also called 'precision dribbling') has become far more effective and done correctly it can oftentimes get you past a sloppy defender and into a good shooting position. Just use the left analog stick without sprinting and try to curve your way through the defense in the right moment. Try to anticipate the defenders move and get him on the wrong foot.
- You can slow down your pace further for more precision by holding <kbd>L1</kbd>.
- When you are trying to outrun a defender, bump the right analog stick into the direction you are running. Your player will push the ball further in front of him, allowing you to run faster.
- Practice single skill moves in the arena, not only against the GK but against actual defenders. You can create game situations by pressing <kbd>select</kbd> in the arena.
- You can view the skill moves list when you are in the main menu by clicking *Customize FIFA -> Settings -> Controls -> Button Help -> Skill Moves*
- Skill moves I found most useful when the defender is in front of you are *Heel Chop* and *Roulette*.

I am far from being an expert on skill moves, but for new players this should help get you started. Effective use takes a lot of practice and while looking cool, for the casual player the amount of time it takes to master them isn't justified by the edge you gain. But if you want to become a really good FIFA player and be competitive online I guess you have to learn them sooner or later.

Comment: I'm an old FIFA fan, have played all games since FIFA 2000 (except 06) in hardest difficulty level available. I never played online games. Until FIFA 11, I can easily beat Legendary difficulty level. Now learning FIFA 12. But I never use any skill moves. It is easy to beat the AI without any skill moves. I'm wondering, how important skill moves are in real competitive online games.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is learn how to run while utilizing both left and right stick. By gently holding the right stick for first touch and such, you can get stronger and more explosive first-step.

The control scheme is all about momentum and balancing your player, but it really just takes timing and paying attention to the smallest details.

Timing is everything, and be patient. Walking in tight spaces calmly or at a controlled 
pace helps skill moves. Try learing a basic skill move, my go to is a classic stepover.

Also tap x than A quickly in the box is easy and effective.